# Getting the image URL without the HTML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

In Rails is there a way to get the URL to the image (going through the assets_host) and just return the URL of the image? I want to use assets_host data in my Javascript, but I just need to insert the URL into the JS, not the whole image_tag.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`image_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#M001720) will return (you guessed it) the path to the image. It's the same method used in `image_tag`.

Comment: for full image url check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597127/rails-3-1-absolute-url-to-an-image

Comment: Updated links! Relative path to image: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path
Absolute path: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_url