# Rails 3.1 absolute URL to an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.1. I'm trying to figure this out, and to my surprise, it is starting to seem that rails does not come with this method at all. Maybe im wrong.

Can anyone show how I can get a full absolute URL to an image?

I use `asset_path(image.png)` which gives me the relative path to use within the app. I tried doing a `root_url + asset_path(image.png)` but that just gives me a `http://localhost:3000//assets/image.png` with the double slashes

Anyone have an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/absolute-url-full-url-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See the **Using asset hosts** section in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html). You need to specify an `asset_host`. You can also construct it dynamically from the request chaining `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"`

Comment: it seems like assets_host applies to all calls of asset_path, i just need an absolute url to an image once. I will look in to the request chaining

Comment: Use `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path("image.png")}"`

Comment: Be careful when using `#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path("image.png")}`. If you set `config.action_controller.asset_host` option in your application configuration, then asset_path will return absolute url and you'll get something like `http://example.comhttp://cdn.example.com/assets/image.png`.

Comment: Simone, please mention that asset_url is not present in Rails 3! I just wasted 10 minutes researching it.

Comment: It should be in Rails 3, this question was referencing Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 24):

put this in `application_helper.rb`

```
def asset_url asset
  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path(asset)}"
end
```

then you can use `asset_url` in your views.

Comment: This returns whatever subdomain I am currently in

Answer (score 12):

For Rails 4, and maybe earlier, use:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://assets.com'
```

per https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails/issues/16

Comment: Actually (at least in rails4+) you want to use `config.asset_host` so it is set for all subsystems not just action mailer.

Answer (score 6):

In my `config/environments/*.rb` I already have this tailored for each environment:

```
config.domain = 'mysite.dev'
```

So it was a simple matter of adding

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://" + config.domain
```

to each file. Then `asset_path` will miraculously behave as if it were `asset_url`.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to put the protocol in there, just configuring `asset_host` should make `asset_path` add the protocol and hostname prefix.

Comment: I find this rails behaviour wrong, `asset_path` should be a path `asset_url` should be an url. I really don't like the way rails change the asset_path behaviour if there's a `asset_host` =/

Answer (score 0):

Example folder structure.

```
app/
   assets/
      flags/
         32x32/
            en.png
         256x256/
            en.png
```

If you want to generate absolute flag image path we can add in to our ApplicationHelper two methods:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Generate flag path by locale
  # - locale. Can be "en", "it", etc.
  # - flag_size. Will be used to set folder size. Folder size can be "32x32", "256x256".
  # Return flag image path. Path will absolute
  def generate_flag_path_by_locale(locale, folder_size = "32")
    folder = "#{flag_size}x#{flag_size}"
    domain_absolute_path = generate_domain_absolute_path
    flag_path = ("#{domain_absolute_path}/assets/flags/#{folder}/#{locale}.png")

    return flag_path
  end

  # Generate domain absolute path
  def generate_domain_absolute_path
    request_protocol = request.protocol
    request_host_with_port = request.host_with_port
    domain_absolute_path = request_protocol + request_host_with_port

    return domain_absolute_path
  end
end
```

Into our apps/view/products.html.erb. We must to call only:

```
<% flag_path = generate_flag_path_by_locale("en") %>
```

Final result:

http://my_domain.com:3000/assets/flags/32x32/en.png

Answer (score -1):

Could you just do:

```
root_url[0..-2] + asset_path(image.png)
```

...to trim the trailing slash in the root url?

Answer (score -10):

You need to use '**asset_url**' instead *asset_path*.

Bcz '_path' always return relative path and '_url' will return absolute url.

Comment: already tried that. there is no such method as asset_url. here's what I get `undefined method `asset_url'`

Comment: please try this ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.example.com"  or check the link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Comment: it seems like assets_host applies to all calls of asset_path, i just need an absolute url to an image once.

Comment: If you want only once, then in such case you can use your own customize helper method.

Comment: `asset_url` doesn't exist in CSS like the _path vs. _url naming convention does elsewhere in helpers. The CSS helper titled `asset-url` (notice the dash instead of underscore) doesn't work in the same convention, but instead just attaches a `url('image.png')` framework to the CSS data.