# Carrierwave default_url from mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have everything working fine, but I realized that when I send out an email from Rails with a default_url, it tries to access:

```
http://assets/fallback/profile_thumb_default.png
```

Here is my default_url code in carrierwave:

```
def default_url
 asset_path("fallback/profile_" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
end
```

asset_url is not a method. Any other suggestions on how to access the default image from an external source (eg. email).

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597127/rails-3-1-absolute-url-to-an-image

Comment: I had seen that. The problem is I can't access "request" commands (get current URL) from the carrierwave uploader.