# Using ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper and asset_path in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am trying to make a `MissingImage` class like this:

```
class MissingImage

  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

  def src format
    return asset_path('layout/missing_image.png')
  end
end
```

To use like this in the model:

```
def main_image
  images.find(&:ismain) || images.first || MissingImage.new
end
```

The problem is - `asset_path` when used like this simply returns the string without any connection to the asset pipeline.

Suggestions?

**UPDATE**

After pocking around I have refactored `MissingImage` somewhat, but it still doesn't generate signed asset path in production:

```
class MissingImage
  def src format
    return ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('layout/missing_image.png')
  end
end
```

The path returned is `/assets/layout/missing_image.png`

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes '/assets/icons/myimage.png' was good enough but it sounds like you want the fully qualified path.  I think if you try to get an absolute url you might have better luck.

You could set the option on the config.action_controller.asset_host and then use:

#{asset_path("layout/missing_image.png")}

check out the comments in the accepted answer on this question - 
[Rails 3.1 absolute URL to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597127/rails-3-1-absolute-url-to-an-image)