# Proper rails image_tag path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, path

I am trying to put an image on a mailer view using `<%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "logo") %>`. This works using an online link so I think the problem is figuring out the path. When the email is sent, the image does not appear and only the text 'logo' is showing.

I have the logo image at `project_name > app > assets > images > logo.png`.

I also have a public directory structured `project_name > public > assets > image_and_js_files`

What is the proper path I should use?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`<%= image_tag("/assets/logo.png", :alt => "logo")`

Comment: I've tried this before. It only shows me the text 'logo'. I've also tried all the directories above it with the same result.

Comment: can you give me more information 1) what's the link generated 2) the file path you suppose to use

Comment: There is no link generated. Just a text 'logo' where I want the logo image to appear. I am trying to figure out the file path. I know the image is in ``project_name > app > assets > images > logo.png`` and in ``project_name > public > assets > image_in_some_format``.

Comment: how about `image_path`?

Comment: I tried using ``<%= image_tag("#{image_path 'logo.png'}", :alt => "logo") %>``. It still only shows text 'logo'.

Comment: it only show text logo, is because link is empty, or the image can not find. what's the html generated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57643/discussion-between-allenwei-and-user1584575).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the absolute link in your email in order to get it works. `image_tag` will only generate relative path, ex: /assets/logo.png.

Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561439/461640

Comment: Can you elaborate further? For now, I am accessing my files in my ``assets`` folder. I do not have a CDN delivering my files. Does asset hosting allow use of relative paths?