# How to get the full URL to an asset in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Does Rails have a built in helper to get the url of an image in the asset pipeline?

```
path_to_image('image.jpg')
```

gets the relative path.

```
url_to_image('image.jpg')
```

doesn't seem to work.

```
"#{root_url}#{path_to_image('image.jpg')}"
```

is not very convenient (and gives an extra / between the root and the image path).

Is there a built in method that I'm overlooking? Or do I need to create a helper?

Comment: Do you actually need the path or do you just want to use it in a template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is built into Rails.

In the end I resorted to a helper method

```
def image_url(file)
  request.protocol + request.host_with_port + path_to_image(file)
end
```

This approach gets around the double slash issue of using `root_url + image_path(file)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `image_path`

Duplicate : [Getting the image URL without the HTML in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875702/getting-the-image-url-without-the-html-in-rails)

More info : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path

**Update**

A helper that could derive your task.

```
def image_url(source)
  "#{root_url}#{image_path(source)}"
end
```

Comment: thanks Trip. image_path is an alias to path_to_image. Unfortuanetly it doesnt work in this case

Comment: Hey Andy, is it that it doesn't work? Or is it that that is not what you are looking for?

Comment: 'image_path' is the same as 'path_to_image'. It is what I'm already using

Comment: Not sure what it is you're looking for.

Comment: i;m looking for a helper that interacts with the asset pipeline, and returns something like `http://example.com/assets/image.jpg`. Both the `image_path` and the `path_to_image` helpers return `/assets/image.jpg`. Appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Hmm.. I would imagine you would have to build something custom then in a helper for this. The reason being that image_path and its alias only go to the root and not the `host` is because the `host` in any given application could be three or more different parts. But its' helper wouldn't be too difficult. Updated above.